# How to set Alias equivalent when using php built in server

Tags: php, apache

I use php's built in server for development:

`php -S localhost:8888`

How can I add an apache equivalent of `Alias` .. the 000-default.conf looks like this :

`Alias /custom  /var/www/my_project`

Comment: You can't. It's not a full fledged web server, therefore it has only the necessary features to accept connections and run scripts. If you want more, install Apache. http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.webserver.php

Comment: If you want more, install nginx.